Pine Script V5 Trading View: Drawing the same ATR-Box independend of used time frame
I am a beginner in Pine Script5 and I want to draw my daily ATR-Boxes but always use the values from the daily time frame independed on what time frame the chart is set to at the moment.
But I struggle to be able to set the left and right values correctly for the box.new function.
I tried to define the left and right using the request.security function but then I always get an error that tells me that I can only use 500 bar into the future.
Using bar_index I was able to draw the boxes, but the boxes always changes based on what time frame I am using in trading view at the moment.
// Calculate actual ATR, plot +/-ATR and +/-2ATR-Ranges
ATR = ta.atr(5)
ATR2 = 2 * ta.atr(5)

//Left = bar_index[0]
//Right = bar_index[0] +1

Left = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", time_tradingday[0] ) // Set the x-value ==> left for the box function indepentend on which time frame I am in at the moment

Right = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", time_tradingday[0] +1)// Set the x-value ==> right for the box function indepentend on which time frame I am in at the moment

ATRBox = box.new(left = Left, top = open + ATR, right = Right, bottom = open - ATR, border_color = color.yellow, border_width = 1, border_style = line.style_solid, bgcolor = color(na))
box.delete(ATRBox[7]) 

Is some one able to show me what I am doing wrong?
With kind regards
ingo

You can learn the use of request.security in this revisited [PineCoders]
Open = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

You can save the value of Left in a variable, when there is a new daily Open
var Left = 0
Left := Open != Open[1] ? bar_index : Left[1]

For the Top and Bootm values ​​you can use the same technique. the ATR must also be daily (request.security)
ATR = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", ta.atr(5), lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
var Top = 0.0
Top := Open != Open[1] ? Open + ATR : Top[1]

var Bottom = 0.0
Bottom := Open != Open[1] ? Open - ATR : Bottom[1]

and finally, you must delete the boxes that you do not use
ATRBox = box.new(left = Left, top = Top, right = bar_index, bottom = Bottom, border_color = color.yellow, border_width = 1, border_style = line.style_solid, bgcolor = color(na))
if Open == Open[1]
    box.delete(ATRBox[1])

